# How to compare values in 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list as   `Users = new List<string>();`

I have another List, `List<TestList>()`;

```
UsersList = new List<string>();
```

I need to compare the values from Users with TestList.Name.  If the value in TestList.Name is present in Users, I must must not add it to UsersList, else, I must add it to UsersList.

How can I do that using Linq?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks to me like you want:

```
List<string> usersList = testList.Select(x = > x.Name)
                                 .Except(users)
                                 .ToList();
```

In other words, "use all the names of the users in `testList` *except* those in `users`, and convert the result to a `List<string>`".

That's assuming you don't have anything in `usersList` to start with. If `usersList` already exists and contains some values, you could use:

```
usersList.AddRange(testList.Select(x = > x.Name).Except(users));
```

Note that this *won't* take account of the existing items in `usersList`, so you may end up with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Do a loop on you list - for example :

```
foreach (string s in MyList)
{
   if (!MyList2.Contains(s))
   {
      // Do whatever ; add to the list
      MyList2.Add(s);
   }  
}
```

..that's how I interpreted you question

Comment: The question ask "How can I do that using Linq?" which this doesn't really answer.

Comment: @Brian Thanks! how did you do the syntax highlighting? I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: Check [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)